# How to delete a wallet

Tags: cleos, wallet, keosd

I am a bit confused about the wallet location in my system.
 I have created a wallet named `mywallet` using `cleos`. then I opened `eosio_wallet` directory and I found `mywallet.wallet` file. I deleted `mywallet.wallet` file and run `cleos wallet list` command. Still, I found `mywallet` in the list. 
**Is there a way to remove the created wallet?**

Comment: Did you used `--wallet-dir` to specify you wallet location generally it is located on `~/eosio-wallet`

Comment: You should first use `cleos wallet open -n your_wallet` this through the error with the path that `keosd ` is accessing, there you can delete the wallets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before deleting the wallet stop the wallet using

`cleos wallet stop -n wallet_name`

and then delete the wallet i guess this will help

Comment: "cleos wallet stop" works

Comment: Happy to hear that @Muhzin

Answer (score 0):

From some sources I understood, Unix systems keep deleted files alive in a zombie-like state as long as any processes have them open. So deleted wallet will remain in a virtual state until keosd is killed